# Highchart X-axis label too long

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please refer the picture attached below.
My X-Axis labels too long and Highchart managed to view only 3 characters.
What code should add to view the entire label?

[image: My highchart]

```
            xAxis: {
                categories: []

            },
```

---

#### Solved

I added in "marginBottom: 70" and able to show full label. refer below.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
    
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',

                marginBottom: 70,
                marginRight: 130
                
            },
            title: {
                text: 'All Gantries Instertions',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
        
                categories: [],

            },
```

Comment: Post our own solution then :)

Comment: Solution posted above, together with the question.

Comment: You should basically post your solution as an answer. Now someone is lost what was the problem and what piece was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use lable formatter with useHTML=true and inside that use custom class.

Your xAxis node will look something like below.

```
       xAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<span class="XYZ">' + this.value + '</span>';
                },
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
```

Apply your class with some custom css instead of XYZ.

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.useHTML) as true and define width of label. Morever you can increase [spacingBottom](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacingBottom) parameter.

```
xAxis: {
   labels: {
      useHTML:true,
      style: {
           width: 50 //where 50 is value in pixels
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer. :)